# How can I install Pixelorama on Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, snap

I'm absolutely new to Linux, I'm currently using Deepin 20. I wanted to install pixelorama, an app for pixel art so I opened the terminal, installed snap and runned the command :
`sudo snap install pixelorama` .

Then I checked my apps' list but I didn't find the app though it said in the terminal :
snap "pixelorama" is already installed

So what can I do to install it correctly? And could you give me a short explanation on what are snaps and how do they work in Linux ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snaps are a special packaging format for software developed by the company *Canonical*, which is also the company maintaining and developing Ubuntu. One of the main differences to other software packages is, that Snap packages are sandboxed and self-contained - like flatpaks if you know those.

You can make sure that your snap was installed correctly by opening a terminal and typing: `ls /snap/bin`. `pixelorama` should be listed in there.

Start it with `snap run pixelorama`

I don't know what is the default shell on deepin, but your problem could be related to the executables not being added to your PATH. When using `zsh` you can fix that with:
`emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile'`